# Angular. NgIf async boolean with ordinary boolean doesn't work

Tags: angular, asynchronous, boolean, observable, angular-ng-if

I have this code

```
(selectCurrentErrorCode$ | async) || data.isError ? 'error' : 'no error'
```

sometimes I need check async Error from state (Observable), and sometimes I want to pass the error directly (data.isError). But with this example, Observable doesnt work

How I can solve this case?

i tried to make 2 separate blocks but it doesn't look nice

Comment: What about using a function instead?

Comment: can you provide code of your Observable? I think problems is in there

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! People will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. Please, create a minimal reproducible example: stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I recommend simply building a secondary Observable that does all of the work:

```js
this.errorText$ = this.selectCurrentErrorCode$.pipe(
  map(errorCode => errorCode || this.data.isError ? 'error' : 'no error')
);
```

And in the template, you simply use

```html
<element *ngIf="errorText$ | async"></element>
```

It is bad practice to mix and match Observables and static variables, especially in the template. Also, don't use a function for this as one commenter suggested, as it will be called for every change detection cycle. Very bad practice.